# Why does FindWindowEx() produce null results?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msdn

I'm trying to find an opened window called "VirtualKeyboard".
This is currently achieved using the following code:-

```
LPCWSTR WindowName =L"SoftKeyboard.exe*32";

HWND Find = ::FindWindowEx(0, 0,WindowName, 0);
cout<<Find<<endl;
```

The WindowName is obtained from task manager,I have initialized it to be the process name called SoftKeyboard.exe*32.I have also tested it using the task name called Virtual_Keyboard but both produce NULL results.The window was opened before running this program.

I placed a break-point at the line containing " HWND Find = ::FindWindowEx(0, 0,WindowName, 0);".The following appeared in the Autos window:-

```
 -      Find    0xcccccccccccccccc {unused=??? }    HWND__ *
        unused  CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
```

How can this be corrected?Why is this occuring?Is the WindowName be extracted from the task manager?Is there an alternative method to find this window?

Comment: Variable Find will become initialized only *after* the line where it's initialized.

Comment: That is correct but the output displayed from cout<<Find is zero !

Comment: Read the error message produced at the last two lines of the code.

Comment: You are mixing two issues. First issue is that Find variable is not initialized on the line with `FindWindowEx`. Move the breakpoint one line below and you will see that Find variable is then properly initialized. Second issue is why `FindWindowEx` is returning 0. It is returning 0 becuase there is no window with window class named "SoftKeyboard.exe*32". This string is not how the window class is named. It is only how a **process** is named in Task Manager, which is not the same as window class name.

Comment: The window class name is the title name appearing on the top of the window,please correct me if im wrong.This will be Virtual_Keyboard.I did move it below:--  Find 0x0000000000000000 {unused=??? } HWND__ * and   unused CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated are appearing in the auto window.

Comment: Is there an alternative method to determine if the Window is opened or exist?Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find out the window class name of the window you want to find. You currently know only that the process from which the window is created is SoftKeyboard.exe. First you have to determine Process ID of this process. In Task Manager Process ID is usually in the second column, right next to executable name. Use Spy++, or the following temporary piece of code to discover all the window class names that belong to this process:

```
BOOL CALLBACK WriteWindowClass(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD nThreadID, nProcessID;
    nThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &nProcessID);

    if (nProcessID == XXX) // Write SoftKeyboard's Process ID instead of XXX
    {
        WCHAR szClassName[256];
        GetClassName(hWnd, szClassName, 256);

        std::wcout << szClassName << std::endl;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) 
{
    EnumWindows(WriteWindowClass, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

You will probably see only one line in console. Text in this line is the class name, and this text should be given to `FindWindowEx` as third parameter, instead of existing "SoftKeyboard.exe*32".

For the "unused CXX0030" issue just google it: unused CXX0030. You will see that this is normal.

Comment: This code works fine,however there is one small issues that did arise,the process ID is not a constant value.Each time I open and close the Virtual Keyboard app the Process ID does change,how can this be solved?

Comment: The route I was thinking of going was to find the process ID of a given process name,in this case it is SoftKeyboard.Refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/12137/ However ,I have not tested it and will have to get back to you on whether it works.If you know of a simpler solution,any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Kribz, the purpose of the code above is not to find the window. The purpose is to find window class name. You have to run the code only once. When you get window class name use it to call `FindWindowEx`, like you wanted to from the start. Please read the text after the code.

Comment: @Kribz, the code above is temporary. Once you obtain window class name you don't need the code anymore, so just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The window class name is not the name appearing at the top of the window. The only way to determine the window class name is to use the Spy++ tool that comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful,is this the reason the error occurs?